# Finding top count of a value in a table using SQL

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a way to find the top count value of a column by SQL.
If for example this is my data

```
id   type
----------
 1    A
 1    B
 1    A
 2    C
 2    D
 2    D
```

I would like the result to be:

```
1   A
2   D
```

I'm looking for a way to do it without groping by the column I count (type in the example)

Thanks

Comment: What's the expected result if you add another row `(2, C)`?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to do a `GROUP BY ID, TYPE`? I'm afraid that's **THE** way to do it. Any other approach will probably be much more complex and slower.

Comment: Could there be a `(1, D)` or a `(2, A)`?

Answer (score 2):

Statistically, this is called the "mode".  You can calculate it using window functions:

```
select id, type, cnt
from (select id, type, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by id, type
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If there are ties, then an arbitrary value is chosen from among the ties.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the statistic mode (the most often ocurring value):

```
select id, stats_mode(type)
from mytable
group by id
order by id;
```

Not all DBMS support this however. Check your docs, wheher this function or a similar one is available in your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Just `GROUP BY id, type` and keep the rows with the maximum counter:

```
select id, type
from tablename 
group by id, type
having count(*) = (
  select count(*) from tablename group by id, type order by count(*) desc limit 1 
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/okWEAqXgkxCKwiyEgRBD94/0)

Or

```
select id, type
from tablename 
group by id, type
having count(*) = (
  select max(t.counter) from (select count(*) counter from tablename group by id, type) t
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/okWEAqXgkxCKwiyEgRBD94/1)